# jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: flasgger/index.html Flask Executable

Tags: api, flask, swagger, pyinstaller, executable

I have a flask app with swagger integration and want to transform this into an executable.
Therefore I used pyinstaller.
But if I access the /swagger on my localhost I get the error code:
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: flasgger/index.html

Why does this only happen if I convert my program into executable beforehand?

My Code:

```
import json
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flasgger import Swagger
from flasgger.utils import swag_from
from flasgger import LazyString, LazyJSONEncoder


def add_2_numbers(num1, num2):
    output = {"sum_of_numbers": 0}
    sum_of_2_numbers = num1 + num2
    output["sum_of_numbers"] = sum_of_2_numbers
    return output


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SWAGGER"] = {"title": "Swagger-UI", "uiversion": 3}

swagger_config = {
    "headers": [],
    "specs": [
        {
            "endpoint": "apispec_1",
            "route": "/apispec_1.json",
            "rule_filter": lambda rule: True,  # all in
            "model_filter": lambda tag: True,  # all in
        }
    ],
    "static_url_path": "/flasgger_static",
    # "static_folder": "static",  # must be set by user
    "swagger_ui": True,
    "specs_route": "/swagger/",
}

template = dict(
    swaggerUiPrefix=LazyString(lambda: request.environ.get("HTTP_X_SCRIPT_NAME", ""))
)

app.json_encoder = LazyJSONEncoder
swagger = Swagger(app, config=swagger_config, template=template)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Add 2 Numbers!"


@app.route("/add_2_numbers", methods=["POST"])
@swag_from("swagger_config.yml")
def add_numbers():
    input_json = request.get_json()
    try:
        num1 = int(input_json["x1"])
        num2 = int(input_json["x2"])
        res = add_2_numbers(num1, num2)
    except:
        res = {"success": False, "message": "Unknown error"}

    return json.dumps(res)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port=8791)
```

swagger_config.yml:

```
consumes:
- "application/json"
produces:
- "application/json"
parameters:
- in: "body"
  name: "body"
  description: "Accepts a input dictionary of inputs x1 and x2"
  required: true
  schema:
    type: "object"
    properties:
      x1:
        type: "integer"
        format: "int64"
        example : 45
      x2:
        type: "integer"
        format: "int64"
        example : 451
responses:
  405:
    description: "Invalid input"
```

When I start my server out of PyCharm it works well but I get the error message when starting as executable